# How to get payload from a POST in Play 2.0

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to implement a REST API with Play 2.0 (Scala) but I'm getting stuck in POST method. How do I get the payload from Request object? I haven't find any documentation about it and have been unable to figure out from source code.

Comment: This guy access post by binding the URL to the HTTP verb and is then able to access his object directly: http://www.jamesward.com/2011/12/11/tutorial-play-framework-jpa-json-jquery-heroku

Comment: @user309483 At the moment, I don't need any implicit binding from payload to beans, anyway, thanks for the link, it may be useful :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

```
def index = Action { request =>
  val body = request.body
}
```

And also things like:

```
def index = Action { request =>
  val name = request.queryString.get("name").flatMap(_.headOption)
  Ok("Hello " + name.getOrElse("Guest"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I've put a `println(request.body)` and I'm getting things like `AnyContent(Map(body -> WrappedArray(pepe), pepe -> WrappedArray(null)))`, which looks like a good start.

Answer (score 8):

have a look at [this article](http://playlatam.wordpress.com/2012/05/21/play-framework-posted-values-revisited/) on [playlatam](http://playlatam.wordpress.com)

also check [this question](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/70d6560d1b71bd9f/2417d8181aecb5b8?lnk=gst&q=opensas%20post%20easy#2417d8181aecb5b8) on google list

for java (with a param names java_name):

```
String name = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("java_name")[0];
```

for scala (with a param names scala_name):

```
def name = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("scala_name")(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to do it somewhat differently (maybe I'm on a newer version of the codebase):

my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.post( "/ping", {one: "one", two: "two" },
    function( data ){
      console.log(data); //returns {"one":"one","two":"two"}
    })
});
```

my route:

```
POST /ping controllers.Application.ping()
```

My controller method:

```
def ping() = Action{ request =>

  val map : Map[String,Seq[String]] = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.getOrElse(Map())

  val one : Seq[String] = map.getOrElse("one", List[String]())
  val two : Seq[String] = map.getOrElse("two", List[String]())

  Ok( 
    toJson( JsObject(List( "one"->JsString(one.first), "two"->JsString(two.first))))
  )
}
```

I assume this will change in the final version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did.

```
val map : Map[String,Seq[String]] = request.body
val seq1 : Seq[String] = map.getOrElse("socket_id", Seq[String]())
val seq2 : Seq[String] = map.getOrElse("channel_name", Seq[String]())
val socketId = seq1.head
val channelName = seq2.head
```