# How could i change CONTENT-TYPE of WebView#PostUrl()?

Tags: android, post, webview, content-type

in Android WebView.

i'm trying to Use WebView#postUrl() with postData.
but i couldn't find the way of changing the Content-Type of request. it's always **"application/x-www-form-urlencoded".**

How can I change that?

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n");
    sb.append("<resource>\r\n");
    sb.append("<element a=\"a\" b=\"b\"/>\r\n"); 
    sb.append("</resource>");
    String postData = sb.toString();

    mWebView.postUrl(url, postData.getBytes());
```

Thank you!

Comment: did you get an answer for this

Comment: Anybody have a solution for this in 2022?

Answer (score 0):

From the `WebView` documentation, it looks like you're stuck with the default `content-type`. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620076/how-to-get-payload-from-a-post-in-play-2-0) to be helpful with parsing the data in my `API` endpoint since I couldn't change the `content-type` to `application/json` or something easier to digest.